# Finding a set based solution instead of looping through each row in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with power outage information, which looks like this,

```
KEY     OUTAGE TIME     POWER LINE ID
1       1/1 2:30 pm     75
2       1/5 4:00 pm     247
3       1/5 6:00 pm     247
4       1/3 8:00 am     11
```

KEY is just the primary key of the table. Outage time tells us when the outage occurred, and power line ID is just the identification number of the line that the outage occurred on.

I have a second table with meter information, that looks like this,

```
event_ID      event_timestamp     event_info        POWER LINE ID
44            1/5 1:45 pm         power on          247
45            1/5 1:45 pm         power on          247
46            1/5 3:45 pm         fault detected    247
47            1/5 3:55 pm         power off         247
48            1/5 3:58 pm         power off         247
49            1/5 5:15 pm         power on          247
50            1/5 5:45 pm         power off         247
51            1/5 5:50 pm         power off         247
52            1/5 5:55 pm         power off         247
53            1/5 5:59 pm         power off         247
```

The goal is the following: For each outage, select all the meter events that happened on that power line before the outage time, and after the most recent "power on" signal that occurred on that power line.

For example, for outage #2, we would look at all the meter events before 1/5 4:00 pm (outage time), but all the events that occurred after 1/5 1:45 pm, since this is the most recent "power on" signal that occurred before the outage. For outage #3, we would look at all the events that occurred before 1/5 6:00 pm (outage time), but after 1/5 5:15 pm, since this is the most recent "power on" signal that occurred before the outage time.

I have done this with a cursor that loops through the outage table and calls a stored procedure that selects the desired events from the events table, but these tables are very large and the cursor is taking too long. I would like to know of a set-based way to approach this problem. Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, I completely forgot to post the sample output. Here it is.

```
KEY    event_ID   POWER LINE ID
2      46         247
2      47         247
2      48         247
3      50         247
3      51         247
3      52         247
3      53         247
```

EDIT (again): I'm looking for a solution to this in Oracle. I'm sorry for the edits, first time posting a question on here.

Comment: I've removed ambiguous DBMS tags pending your edit that would include the proper one. Answers may be specific for different database systems.

Comment: Do I understand this question? For each `outage` row in your table, do you want to select all the `event` rows **except** those with timestamps between the outage timestamp and the largest "power on" timestamp? Another question: what are the datatypes in your tables of the `OUTAGE TIME` and `event_timestamp` columns?

Comment: @jpw I have added the sample output

Comment: @OllieJones I would like to select all the rows with timestamps between the outage timestamp and the largest "power on" timestamp that occurred before the outage timestamp. The datatype is timestamp(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm solving the problem using SQL Server so `#` means temp table.

Assuming below tables and data

```
create table #outage ([key] int, outage_time datetime, power_line int)

insert into #outage values 
(1,       '2015/1/1 2:30 pm',     75),
(2,       '2015/1/5 4:00 pm',    247),
(3,       '2015/1/5 6:00 pm',    247),
(4,       '2015/1/3 8:00 am',     11)

create table #even (event_ID int , event_time datetime, 
                    event_info varchar(20), power_line int)

insert into #even values
(44,            '2015/1/5 1:45 pm'         ,'power on'          ,247),
(45,            '2015/1/5 1:45 pm'         ,'power on'          ,247),
(46,            '2015/1/5 3:45 pm'         ,'fault detected'    ,247),
(47,            '2015/1/5 3:55 pm'         ,'power off'         ,247),
(48,            '2015/1/5 3:58 pm'         ,'power off'         ,247),
(49,            '2015/1/5 5:15 pm'         ,'power on'          ,247),
(50,            '2015/1/5 5:45 pm'         ,'power off'         ,247),
(51,            '2015/1/5 5:50 pm'         ,'power off'         ,247),
(52,            '2015/1/5 5:55 pm'         ,'power off'         ,247),
(53,            '2015/1/5 5:59 pm'         ,'power off'         ,247)
```

This is the query:

```
select o.[key], e.event_ID, o.power_line
from #outage o
    inner join #even e on e.power_line = o.power_line
    and e.event_time < o.outage_time
    and e.event_time > (select max(event_time) from #even 
                        where power_line = o.power_line 
                            and event_time < o.outage_time 
                            and event_info = 'power on')
```

Comment: Oh I see how you did it, first the join pairs the outage IDs to the events based on the power line ID, and then you pick the events you want based on the criteria. It's so much faster than the cursor, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT power_outage.key,
       meters.event_id,
       power_outage.power_line_id
FROM   power_outage
JOIN   meter_info meters
  ON   power_outage.power_line_id = meters.power_line_id
 AND   meters.event_timestamp < power_outage.outage_time
WHERE  meters.event_timestamp > (SELECT MAX(lpo.event_timestamp)
                                 FROM   meter_info lpo -- LastPowerOn
                                 WHERE  lpo.power_line_id = power_outage.power_line_id
                                   AND  lpo.event_info = 'power on'
                                   AND  lpo.event_timestamp < power_outage.outage_time);
```

The 'JOIN' gets all elements as far as they occurred before the outage time while the condition filters the elements corresponding to the most recent power on.

Comment: I noticed my answer is more or less equal to the one FLICKER posted just before I did. I saw that answer only after having posted mine.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little longer query involving `CTE`, but easier to understand on a step-by-step basis:

```
WITH events_before_outage AS (
select
  ot.key, ot.outage_time, ot.power_line_id, mi.event_id, mi.event_timestamp, mi.event_info
from outage_table ot
left join meter_information mi
  on ot.power_line_id = mi.power_line_id
  and ot.outage_time > mi.event_timestamp
)
, last_power_on AS (
select key, max(event_timestamp) as event_date
from events_before_outage
where event_info = 'power on'
group by 1
)
select a.key, a.event_id, a.power_line_id
from events_before_outage a
where a.event_timestamp > ( select event_date from last_power_on b where a.key = b.key )
order by 1,2
```

Outputs:

```
 key | event_id | power_line_id
-----+----------+---------------
   2 |       46 |           247
   2 |       47 |           247
   2 |       48 |           247
   3 |       50 |           247
   3 |       51 |           247
   3 |       52 |           247
   3 |       53 |           247
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely set-based approach using analytic functions.  The idea is to enumerate the "poweron"s by doing a cumulative count of them to get groups.  Then, use this group to get the time of any power outages during the group, and return the values.

```
select om.*
from (select om.*,
             max(om.outagetime) over (partition by poweron_grp, powerlineid) as outagetime,
             min(event_timestamp) over (partition by powerongrp, powerlineid as minet,
             max(event_timestamp) over (partition by powerongrp, powerlineid as maxet
      from (select m.*, o.outagetime,
                   sum(case when m.event_info = 'power on' then 1 else 0 end) over
                       (partition by m.powerlineid order by m.event_timestamp
                       ) as poweron_grp
            from outages o join
                 meters m
            on o.powerlineid = m.powerlineid
           ) om
     ) om
where outagetime between minte and maxte and
      event_timestamp < outagetime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Several of the proposed answers use a correlated subquery using the full meter information table, even though they only NEED the rows for event_info = 'power on'. Correlated subqueries are evaluated for each successive row, so all those unneeded rows are evaluated - and discarded - many times. So if there are many events with event_info different from 'power on', which appears to be the case, then additional efficiency can be achieved by isolating just the 'power on' events.

Here is one way to do that. I gave the tables the names outage_data and meter_data, and in the outage_data table I named the "key" column outage_ID; it is a really bad idea to use keywords as column names, and key ... is ... a keyword! The subquery (cte) p is evaluated once, it just collects the events with event_info = 'power on', and the correlated subquery is against p, not against the full meter_data table.

```
with p as (select power_line, event_time from meter_data where event_info = 'power on')
select   o.outage_ID, m.event_ID, o.power_line
from     outage_data o join meter_data m on m.power_line = o.power_line
where    m.event_time <= o.outage_time 
  and    m.event_time > (select max(p.event_time) from p 
                      where p.power_line = o.power_line and p.event_time <= o.outage_time)
order by o.outage_ID, m.event_ID
```